# Facebook Graph Api Like custom action approval changes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I create a custom facebook graph action named "Like" with my custom object say "Photo" and also set Inherits From to Like. Now when i submit for approval they send back for changes with following message :

"I'm trying to submit a custom action that is not allowed. Remove this action, please submit this action instead of the embedded version.".

So my question is that what i need to change in this case?

Comment: I am using this for web application.